# How to return only certain echo to the caller in shell

Tags: shell, echo, stdout

I have a shell script like

sample.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# some git operations
echo "some informative logs 1"
echo "some informative logs 2"
echo "some informative logs 3"
echo "some informative logs 4"
if some_condition ; then
  echo "This condition evaluated true"
else
  echo "This condition evaluated false"
fi
```

and in another script, I am calling the above script like

```
result=$(sh sample.sh)
echo "------- " $result
```

This works fine, but the `result` contains all logs from `sample.sh`. What I am trying to do is, get only the final result of the script in `result`. For that, I can append `>dev/null` to every line. But that will eliminate all informative logs from the console.

In short, is there any way to return certain values only(not logs from all commands) to the caller and print logs in the console from a shell script?

Comment: If it's the last line only, you could do `result=$(sh sample.sh | tail -n 1)` to save just the last line. Another idea is to make all the log lines write to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: @rchome actually ont last line, it can be multiple lines.

Comment: Are the lines you want to save greppable?